# ./configure not able to find libusb, build fails

Tags: macos, configure, libusb-1.0

Using macOS Venture Version 13.5.1
brew install libusb succeeds, but subsequent ./configure is unable to find libusb, fails with the following error

Library libusb-1.0 was not found on this system.
Please install it and re-run ./configure

Here's an inline link to the error: `[pastebin.com] https://pastebin.com/xdvhbwAK`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the configure script cannot find the (libusb library). This can happen for a few reasons:

1. The libusb library is not installed.
2. The libusb library is installed in a non-standard location.
3. The configure script is not using the correct flags to find the libusb library.

To fix this, you can try the following:

Make sure that the libusb library is installed. You can do this by running the following command:

```
brew install libusb
```

If the libusb library is installed, make sure that the configure script can find it. You can do this by setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to the directory where the libusb library is installed. For example, if the libusb library is installed in
**/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig**, you would set the **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** environment variable to **/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig**.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```